# How to change tax calculation parameters at Woocoomerce checkout?

Tags: javascript

Can you help me?
In Brazil we have a very different way of calculating taxes than in other countries. He follows:
1 - If the value of the product is less than R$ 250.00

a) Add the value of the Product + Shipping;
b) Add ICMS of 17% to the previous value;
c) include the Post Office customs clearance fee, which is a fixed amount of R$ 15.00
d) Give the total sum

2 - If the value of the product is greater than R$ 250.00

a) Add the value of the Product + shipping;
b) Add the Import Tax of 60% on the previous value
c) Add the ICMS of 17% on the previous value
d) include the Post Office customs clearance fee, which is a fixed amount of R$15.00 on top of the previous amount.
e) Give the total sum

Follow the code. I do not know if it's right. I thank everyone who can help me.

Comment: Please add the relevant JS you're having issues with. Read [ask] then [edit] with a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.